# Bootstrap col-*

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I have simple question - I have such code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">...</div>
```

Do I need to use all cols, if they are the same or I can use only one of col-* class?

Comment: if your panel is going to resize itself according to the the width of the browser then you should use different `col` .

Comment: If you need same number of columns then use only the smallest one. `xs` in your case. TB is mobile first so `col-xs-12` will be applied on all above resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

Used for this case is col-xs-*. My advice is that for a readable read always all classes of all columns are used.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">...</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I thing is better to use all bootstrap classes, because every classes it's from different devices. As you know !

It's good to read this - https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

I'll be glad to help you :)